# Plot frequency of events with time in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, plot, histogram

I have a reasonable amount of time data, and I'd like to put it in a frequency graph, where the X-axis would be several intervals of time and the Y-axis would be the amount of data I've collected in such period. See this example:

Let's suppose I have this list:

```
[10:17:55, 10:37:40, 10:40:26, 10:48:18, 11:00:17, 11:01:12, 11:06:58, 11:09:20, 11:43:41, 11:48:24, 11:49:14, 12:07:31, 12:10:52, 12:10:52, 12:19:00, 12:19:00, 12:19:43, 12:20:55, 12:38:27, 12:38:27, 12:55:09, 12:55:10, 12:57:31, 12:57:31, 13:04:16, 13:04:16, 13:06:51   13:06:51, 14:55:06, 14:56:10, 15:01:30, 15:28:42, 3:29:17, 15:35:33, 15:58:32, 16:05:07, 16:09:16, 16:10:36, 16:32:57, 16:32:57, 16:34:32, 16:38:16, 17:43:27, 17:53:01, 17:56:14, 18:08:21, 18:17:23, 18:37:23, 18:37:23, 18:43:13, 18:43:13   18:51:43, 18:51:43, 19:05:39, 19:05:39]
```

And I'd like to plot a histogram showing how many values are there in intervals of 1h, or 30 minutes (still deciding), such as:

```
10h - 11h: 4
11h - 12h: 7
.
.
.
19h - 20h: 2
```

But all that represented in a graph. I know the very basics of how to plot a histogram in R and couldn't figure out how to do that. I've seen some answers making plots throughout the days, which is not much applicable, because these values were collected in different days... Can you guys help me?

EDIT: Here's a `dput()` of the list:

```
structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 
43L, 43L, 44L, 44L), .Label = c("10:17:55", "10:37:40", "10:40:26", 
"10:48:18", "11:00:17", "11:01:12", "11:06:58", "11:09:20", "11:43:41", 
"11:48:24", "11:49:14", "12:07:31", "12:10:52", "12:19:00", "12:19:43", 
"12:20:55", "12:38:27", "12:55:09", "12:55:10", "12:57:31", "13:04:16", 
"13:06:51", "14:55:06", "14:56:10", "15:01:30", "15:28:42", "15:29:17", 
"15:35:33", "15:58:32", "16:05:07", "16:09:16", "16:10:36", "16:32:57", 
"16:34:32", "16:38:16", "17:43:27", "17:53:01", "17:56:14", "18:08:21", 
"18:17:23", "18:37:23", "18:43:13", "18:51:43", "19:05:39"), class = "factor")`
```

Comment: Assuming they are dates: `hist(as.numeric(format(hour_dat,"%H")),breaks=24)`   Basically you want to isolate the hour first. Format will spit out a character, so you need to convert to numeric.

Comment: When I collected them I supressed the date values. I guess now they are pure time data... How would I proceed if so? When I try to apply your solution it throws "invalid 'trim' argument".

Comment: please `dput()` your data.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img911/1969/7qROJ9.png

Comment: Please add the information from that png into the question you asked. A picture of the `dput()` does not allow users to input the information into their R session. Simply [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32952445/edit) the question and then we can help you further.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've just added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are range, trunc and seq methods for POSIXt or Date objects. Assuming you assign that structure object to a name such as `tms` this would convert to POSIXct and then construct a range, a sequence of breaks that spanned the hours and then bin within 30 minute intervals:

```
> tms <- as.POSIXct(tms, format="%H:%M:%S")
> brks <- trunc(range(tms), "hours")
Warning message:
In if (isdst == -1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> hist(tms, breaks=seq(brks[1], brks[2]+3600, by="30 min") )
```

Notice that the plot method for POSIXt objects handles the x-axis labeling:

[image]

I suppose you could check to see if the  second "brks" was within the half-hour window for a 30 minute plot. So this would be the code to avoid a blank bin, if targeting half-hour bins:

```
hist(tms, breaks=seq(brks[1], 
                     brks[2]+ if( as.numeric( max(tms)-brks[2] ) < 30) #diff time in mins
                                   {1800} else{3600},
                    by="30 min")
    )
```

Comment: If I wished to have a different interval, I'd just have to change the `by=30 min`?

Comment: That's right. I was aiming for code that would use the capacity of the seq and/or cut date-time methods which provide that additional flexibility. I couldn't quite figure out how to avoid the possibility of creating an empty break interval, but thought that the flexibility was worth that added "risk". round and trunc don't have the option of quantifying minutes or hours at least as I read their help pages.

Comment: Very nice @BondedDust. Precise and concise!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method I used to obtain what it is you are after.

This will work for hours and half hours. Not the prettiest, but I think it serves your purpose. You will need to do some massaging of the axes so they display the information you desire. Hopefully that helps!

```
hours <- as.numeric( format( strptime( times , format = "%H:%M:%S" ) , "%H" ) )
hist( hours , breaks = unique( hours ) )

half_hours <- hours + ( as.numeric( format( strptime( times , format = "%H:%M:%S" ) , "%M" ) ) /60 )
hist(half_hours , breaks = c( unique( hours ) , unique( hours ) + 0.5 ) )
```